# how to overwrite current theme in yii2.0 with your own theme

Tags: php, yii2-user

I have been trying to use my own downloaded themes in yii2.0. I created a folder called 'themes' in web and copied my theme folder there, then I changed the view in web.php but I still get the default theme.
What can I do to make my theme work?

Comment: you should add the code first people can not help you to build the code and work for you plz add your snippet of work which you have done and if you find any problem in it we can help you for that...

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the pathMap and the view component like described in the [Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-theme.html) ?

Comment: I configured the baseurl and pathMap.